# How do I map TTY consoles to external monitor on laptop which has two graphics outputs?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, tty, console

I have a laptop which contains an integrated Intel graphics chip and a discrete Nvidia graphics card.

When using the XServer the Nvidia drivers manage everything for me and I'm able to connect an external monitor via HDMI and shut off my laptop screen.

When I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I'm taken to `tty1`, however even though I have disabled my laptop screen and enabled the external monitor the `tty1` console always opens up on the laptop screen and not on the external monitor while shutting off my external monitor in the process.

What I was wondering was (I'm sure this is possible, and I'm a firm believer that anything is possible if you know how) how do I get the `tty1` console to open up on the external HDMI monitor and not display on my laptops screen?

I snooped around the internet and read somewhere about `fbcon`, this is my the output of

```
user@computer:~$cat /proc/fb
0 inteldrmfb
```

I read somewhere about how `fbcon` can be used to map the console but I still haven't figured out how that works. I'm not an advanced Linux user. I'm still learning about much of it. I'm able to read man pages for basic commands and figure thing out but this seems beyond what I'm capable of. Some pointers on this topic would be much appreciated. I would really like to have tty console to open up on my external monitor.